# PHP passing parameters via SOAP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am struggling to get to grips with creating the "xml" data for a PHP based SOAP client.  I need to produce something like the following:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:check_stock_level>
<ns1:api_credentials>
<ns1:username>*****</ns1:username>
<ns1:password>***</ns1:password>
</ns1:api_credentials>
<productsku>ABC-123</productsku>
</ns1:check_stock_level>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I can create the authorisation section, but my code fails to create the `productsku` - the code looks like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.example.net/wh_api.asmx?WSDL",array("trace"=> 1, "exceptions" => 0));
$auth = array ('api_credentials' => array ('username'=>'******', 'password'=>'******'));
$sku = array('productsku'=>'ABC-123');
$result = $client->check_stock_level($auth, $sku);
```

which produces this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:check_stock_level>
<ns1:api_credentials>
<ns1:username>*****</ns1:username>
<ns1:password>***</ns1:password>
</ns1:api_credentials>
</ns1:check_stock_level>
<param1>
<item>
<key>product_sku</key>
<value>ABC-123</value>
</item>
</param1>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Where the `productsku` is outside of the `<check_stock_level>` tag set and is surrounded by extra tags.

Most examples I can find on SOAP use NuSOAP but I want to use the native pHP SOAP functionality. Can anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it myself, the two arrays needed to be combined - by having them as separate arrays, the productsku data was moved outside of the  tag set.